# jQuery move/append multiple items with same class name, inside parent div only

Tags: jquery, append, appendto

I have a dynamically generated page with the following structure:

```
<div class="list-item">
    <div class="year">xxx1</div>
    <div class="other-data">xxx1</div>
    <div class="item-title">Title 1</div>
    <div class="item-information"></div>
</div>
<div class="list-item">
    <div class="year">xxx2</div>
    <div class="other-data">xxx2</div>
    <div class="item-title">Title 2</div>
    <div class="item-information"></div>
</div>
```

There are multiple list items on the page.

Within each list-item, I need to take "year" and "other-data" and remove it from above the item-title and appendTo "item-information".

I have tried the following:

```
$('.year').appendTo('.item-information');
$('.other-data').appendTo('.item-information');
```

This does not work properly, as it basically takes ALL instances of "year" and appends it to "item-information" - so if there are 3 items on the page, each item ends up showing 3 instances of "year" in each "item-information".

In order to resolve this, I know I need some kind of statement that selects the list-item, finds year and other-data within that list item, then finds item-information within the same list item and appends it there.

The problem is, I am not sure how to structure the statement, I tried the below but it errored out:

```
$('.list-item').find('.year').appendTo(function({
    $(this).find('.item-information');
});
```

Could someone help me out with the correct structure for what I want to do?

Thanks.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/32bitkid/td4om0wz/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$(".list-item").each(function () {    //loop over each list item
    myYear= $(".year", this);         //get the year of the current list item
    $(".item-information", this).append(myYear); //append it to the item information
});
```

you could do this, then of course for every other list item child element ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `append(function)` and `.siblings()` as follows:

```
$('.item-information').append(function() {  
    return $(this).siblings('.year,.other-data');
});
```

```js
   $('.item-information').append(function() {  
        return $(this).siblings('.year,.other-data');
    });

//output new html
$('pre.out').text( $('<div/>').html( $('div.list-item').clone() ).html() );
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="list-item">
    <div class="year">xxx1</div>
    <div class="other-data">xxx1</div>
    <div class="item-title">Title 1</div>
    <div class="item-information"></div>
</div>
<div class="list-item">
    <div class="year">xxx2</div>
    <div class="other-data">xxx2</div>
    <div class="item-title">Title 2</div>
    <div class="item-information"></div>
</div>

<h1>NEW HTML</h1>
<pre class="out"></pre>
```